# Reference error on kendo graph

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to use a custom y-as for my kendo graph. This is the function.

```
function FormatLongNumber(value) {
  if(value == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
        // for testing
      //value = Math.floor(Math.random()*1001);

      // hundreds
      if(value <= 999){
        return value;
      }
      // thousands
      else if(value >= 1000 && value <= 999999){
        return (value / 1000) + 'K';
      }
      // millions
      else if(value >= 1000000 && value <= 999999999){
        return (value / 1000000) + 'M';
      }
      // billions
      else if(value >= 1000000000 && value <= 999999999999){
        return (value / 1000000000) + 'B';
      }
      else
        return value;
  }
}
```

And when I wanna use this on my kendo graph I use this:

```
valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            visible: true,
            //format: ValueAxisLabelsFormat,
            template: "#= FormatLongNumber(value) #"   
        }
    },
```

When I run the application I get the following error.

```
ReferenceError: FormatLongNumber is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the function `FormatLongNumber` defined inside the angular scope or outside?

Comment: Outside the scope sir is it defined after the function activate(){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormatLongNumber must be a function defined in the global JavaScript scope. Make sure this is the case.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#handle-external-templates-and-expressions